# Group Layer On/Off Behaviour

Tags: qgis, layers, group-layer

One of the main reasons I use groups in Arc and QGIS is to be able to group similar data and/or associated layers which I will want to display or turn on/off together.

In Arc if I have a group with say 5 layers, and I have 2 of those turned on, I can simply turn the entire group off and both those layers will turn off. Importantly though if I then turn the group back on, those two layers turn back on. The 'on/Off' status of each layer within the group is not changed by changing the whole groups On/Off status.

In QGIS when I click to turn a group off QGIS first turns all the layers in that group on, and then on clicking again will turn all the layers off, as per the image below. This is frustrating as I just want to turn the group off to collectively turn those two layers off, and most commonly then back on again after I have published a map or achieved what ever I needed to without those layer displayed.

[image: Group Layer Behaviour]

My question is, is there a way in QGIS 2.18 to turn off a group  while retaining the On/Off status of the layers in the group such as Arc does?

Comment: Not yet - but hopefully soon. See https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2016-November/045780.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and is currently being discussed on https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2016-November/045780.html